# How add values from text field / label to an array when a button click in iphone

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have a text field In that user can enter values from 1-10

at the bottom of the text field i have button.

i need to add the values in text filed to array when user clicks done button

for this i wrote code like this.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    PainlevelsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; //PainlevelsArray declared in .h

}


-(IBAction)doneClick:(id)sender
{
    [PainlevelsArray addObject:txtField.text ];

    // [PainlevelsArray insertObject:rateLabel.text atIndex:0 ];
    NSLog(@"PainlevelsArray *** %@",PainlevelsArray);

   [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

But every time array displays only the recently added one value only in log when button clicks, like this

***Output on Console***

========================

```
2012-05-07 10:11:15.689 ESPT[796:10d03] PainlevelsArray *** (
    2
)
2012-05-07 10:11:27.984 ESPT[796:10d03] PainlevelsArray *** (
    4
)
```

***`My array gets empty every time view loads, and adde a fresh entry when button clicks`***
But i need like this

```
2012-05-07 10:11:27.984 ESPT[796:10d03] PainlevelsArray *** (
        4,
        5,
        2,
        6,
        8,
    )
```

All the velues enters are adde/inserted to the existing array.

Thanks in advance

**in ExerciseStartViewController**

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 ExerciseResult *result = [[ExerciseResult alloc] init];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:result animated:YES];
            [result release];
    }
```

**in current/ ExerciseResult viewcontroller**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    PainlevelsArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; //PainlevelsArray declared in .h

}


-(IBAction)doneClick:(id)sender
{
    [PainlevelsArray addObject:txtField.text ];

    // [PainlevelsArray insertObject:rateLabel.text atIndex:0 ];
    NSLog(@"PainlevelsArray *** %@",PainlevelsArray);

   [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
```

Comment: Describe your view controllers.

Comment: see my described view controllers in edit question

Comment: ok im there in caht list but u are invisable

Comment: See below my posted answer....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a global array.

Best possible solution is declare an array in AppDelegate.h file and alloc-init this array in applicationdidfinishlaunch method.

```
AppDelegate *app =  (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[app.arrMutable addObject:textField.text ];
```

**Use UserDefaults**: These are used to save your application data in key-value format. The values/objects stored as userdefaults always remain in application, until you have not removed it from sandbox. You can use following code to store an array in userdefaults.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:app.arrMutable forKey:@"Global_Array_Key"];
```

In AppDelegae applicationDidFinishLuanch method you can retrieve this array from userdefaults using:

```
self.arrMutable = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"Global_Array_Key"]];
```

Comment: Yes sir this the best ans among all of these but array again gets empty/ reload as fresh when app launches. (instead of view loads)

Comment: you can use NSUserDefaults if you want to access same array after your application relaunches

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare and initialize PainlevelsArray globally, i.e. in AppDelegate or separate class of shared instance, where memory has been assigned once and it won't over write its data even though any number of time you access the said class and so that it will continuously inserts new value into the array and you will get the desired result.

Comment: Or he could pass the value back to the previous view controller when it closes (probably via delegation).  It doesn't necessarily have to be a global variable...

Comment: Global instance will be the best practice instead of set delegate and make code unnecessarily complex.

Comment: Yes  if i declared globally array starts for every time app launches.
In this case array starts every time view loads.
both cases array starts as an empty array.

Comment: Nope, globally declared array will remain empty until very first time said view is being called. After that, every time it will inserts value from the textfield into it. Whereas, if the array starts at time when said view loads, it will remain empty always and it won't continuously adds to the list of previously stored value.

Answer (score 1):

```
ExerciseResult *result = [[ExerciseResult alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:result animated:YES];
[result release];
```

I think you might be fallow this type of code in you action for coming to this view. Instead of this you have to fallow to take as global ExerciseResult *result

in .h

```
ExerciseResult *result;
```

in .m

```
in viewDidLoad

result = [[ExerciseResult alloc] init];
```

in you action method you will fallow

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:result animated:YES];
```

you will follow like that

I hope it will helps you

Answer (score 1):

Declare in Delegate.h page

```
  @interface AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>
  {
       NSMutableArray *commString;
  }
  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *commString;
  @end
```

Delegate.m page

```
  @sythesize commString;

 - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
          commString = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
          // some code.....
 }
```

In your Button view

```
 -(IBAction)doneClick:(id)sender
{
NSMutableArray *mut=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:txtField.text,nil];
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
appDelegate.commString=mut;

   // some code....
}
```

Declare this code where u want your array, you can easily get ur array.

```
   AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
   NSLog(@"commString=%@",appDelegate.commString);
```

Comment: if u works this code accept this question and increase ur points. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You use this line of code when you click just write add this line.

```
[array addobject:textfield.text];
```

use this only.

```
[PainlevelsArray addObject:txtField.text]
```

Comment: If popping the view controller after each entry is desired behavior, he then needs to store the data in the previous view controller instead.

Comment: If it is helpful for you then mark it right so it will be also helpful for other

Comment: I am not understd what are you telling.

Comment: I'm saying that it is possible that Ranga had popToRootViewController there for a reason and that this solution may not work as desired.

Comment: NO that is not the reason for that.

Comment: If you think am not that will be ok for me buddy.

Answer (score 0):

You should use properties for an array in this situation.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *painlevelsArray;
```

Initialize the array

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
self.painlevelsArray = array;
```

Then add your string to the array after each button click

```
[self.painlevelsArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",self.textField.text]];
```

Comment: It's not exactly the same.  He needs to use properties to manage this array.  I am not sure how many view controllers he is using.  He should initialize the array in his main view controller and pass it to the view controller with the button to add an object to it.  We are missing too much code for me to properly answer this.